# Facebook Comments on my Site

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, comments

I've added the Facebook social plug-in to my site, which allows users to comment using their facebook profile. However, I have more than 1 item on a page, and want users to make individual comments, because currently, when a user makes a comment on 1 item, it adds that comment to every item. This is probably because each item is called onto the site using a while loop which echo's and prints every single item stored in my database. Does anyone know if there's a way around this or not? If it helps, the code facebook provides users with is as follows:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=109566779171141";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-href='My URL' data-width='470' data-num-posts='10'></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to assign a unique URL per comment box, even if they are on the same page you are able to use something like:

```
http://www.example.com/#comments1
http://www.example.com/#comments2
http://www.example.com/#comments3
...
```